# Detect wink on Google Glass without taking picture

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk, google-mirror-api

Is there a way to stop Glass from taking picture while listening to wink command?
Whenever I detect Wink from my code, it automatically takes a picture which I don't want.

Edit:
The library is a stub. Whenever the onDetected function is called, I get a log message then Glass takes picture. Is there a way to stop the Internal glass function from running? I tried adding return at the end of onDetected but that didn't work.... Maybe a function to abort to exit the function?
The code is below.

```
@Override
public void onDetected(final EyeGesture eyeGesture) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mAudioManager.playSoundEffect(Sounds.SUCCESS);
            Log.e(TAG, eyeGesture + " is detected");
            if(eyeGesture==target1.WINK){
                mTextView.setText("Detected " + eyeGesture + "!");
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: If you can show me the code used for the detection, I can probably tell you. Is it native? or are you using a library?

Comment: Added the important part of the code. It is a stub library.

Comment: Couldn't find the answer, sorry. You have two options: either figure out how to programmatically turn off the blink for a picture the way you can turn it off in the settings, or find what method is in charge of listening for the wink natively and override it. That's as much as I can help you...good luck!

Comment: In the old days (XE16 and before), winks sent out a broadcast. If you simply created a high priority broadcast receiver, you could abort the broadcast (and the wink-picture-receiver would never see the broadcast). Now the API is completely different - I haven't found a way to override the wink receiver, but you may want to look at the EyeGesture and EyeGestureManager stub classes: https://gist.github.com/victorkp/9094a6aea9db236a97f3

Comment: I am installing glass XE16 image and will try to use Intent Filter and abortBroadcast. Will let you know how that worked out.

Answer (score 1):

In the old days (XE16 and before), winks sent out a broadcast. If you simply created a high priority broadcast receiver, you could abort the broadcast (and the wink-picture-receiver would never see the broadcast).

I put togethher some old code to demonstrate this here: https://gist.github.com/victorkp/0f98cd5c096de53f4518

Comment: I knew about this. It worked on XE16 but not on XE22 which is what I am trying get working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah - I haven't found a solution for anything beyond XE16, so I'm in the same boat as you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

https://github.com/prt2121/EyeGestureLib

Revision for XE19.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question it's recommended that as well as a link it's useful to post relevant details about how you're answering the question, in case the link isn't available.

Comment: I have not explained the answer because I don't know exactly what is the difference between the code that I have published and the code that Victor KP published :( Sorry for the inconvenience